# How to find current running application memory usage in android commands to check its memory uasage?

Tags: android, appium

How to find current memory usage of an application while using through adb command?

Can anyone post me the code that to find the current application memory usage

Comment: after all you want code or Adb Command?

Answer (score 10):

with Android we did it using phones connected to same machine where tests are running.

in test code we just execute:

- adb shell dumpsys cpuinfo
- adb shell dumpsys meminfo 'your apps
  package name'

and in code just parse values needed. then we just printed them in test logs and just manually looked through them.

test itself was kind of walking among many screens and good long swipe with large lists.